# cant figure out whats wrong with my enum dropdown list in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, enums, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

I have the data seeded into a list on the index page into a table and this is the model for the album to create it using entity frame work, this is all the Model.cs

```
public enum genre { Rock=1, Pop=2 }

public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtist { get; set; }
    public genre AlbumGenre { get; set; }
    public Album()
    {
        GenreList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GenreList { get; set; } 
    public List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }  
}
```

The controller has the following code for the dropdown list. I get a redline under `model` in the code at the end, here `return View(model);` however when I run it, it doesn't specify this as the answer.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Album model = new Album();
    IEnumerable<genre> genres = Enum.GetValues(typeof (genre)).Cast<genre>();
    model.GenreList = from action in genres
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = action.ToString(),
                          Value = (action.ToString())
                      };
    return View(model);
}
```

and my index page is where it shows the error.
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AlbumID, model.GenreList)` is the line in which I get the error on `AlbumId` and `GenreList`

```
@model IEnumerable<revision.Models.Album>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create WOW", "Create"
</p>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AlbumID, Model.GenreList)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding to property `AlbumGenre` (not `AlbumID`)?

Answer (score -1):

Enums are supported in Razor views from MVC 5.1. Check if you are using any prior version of mvc. Additionally, [MVC 5.1 Razor DisplayFor not working with Enum DisplayName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334761/mvc-5-1-razor-displayfor-not-working-with-enum-displayname) this will also help you.

Comment: OP has tagged the question MVC-4!