# VB ASP.NET DisplayFor Enum not displaying correctly using DisplayFor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, enums

While trying to get DisplayFor(enum) to show the DisplayName of the Enum instead of the Enum Text I came across this question that pointed me in the right direction:

[MVC 5.1 Razor DisplayFor not working with Enum DisplayName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334761/mvc-5-1-razor-displayfor-not-working-with-enum-displayname)

Using that I created a helper to show the DisplayName instead.

Model:

```
Public Enum QnStatus
    <Display(Name:="Öppen")> Open
    <Display(Name:="Avslutad")> Closed
    <Display(Name:="Väntar på svar från kund")> WaitingOnCustomer
    <Display(Name:="Väntar på svar från leverantör")> WaitingOnSupplier
End Enum
```

Helper:

```
@Model Enum
@If EnumHelper.IsValidForEnumHelper(ViewData.ModelMetadata) Then
Dim displayname As String = ""
For Each item As SelectListItem In EnumHelper.GetSelectList(ViewData.ModelMetadata, DirectCast(Model, [Enum]))
    If item.Selected Then
        If Not IsNothing(item.Text) Then
            displayname = item.Text
        Else
            displayname = item.Value

        End If
    End If
Next

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayname) Then
    If Model Is Nothing Then
        displayname = String.Empty
    Else
        displayname = Model.ToString()
    End If

End If

@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) displayname)

Else
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(Function(model) model)
End If
```

The problem I am having is that now when using DisplayFor in a view it returns the following (example for WaitingOnCustomer):

```
 WaitingOnCustomer Enum Väntar på svar från kund
```

So I get Enum Text + Enum Type + DisplayName.

Without using the helper I get:

```
 WaitingOnCustomer
```

Why is it returning the Enum Text and Type when using the helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper view is currently returning the value of `@Model + the literal text "Enum" + DisplayName`.  To fix it remove the first line, `@Model Enum`, from the helper view and then it will return only the `DisplayName`.