# Enum display attribute doesn't work when published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I got the following view model

```
public enum EnumViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Foo")]
    First,

    [Display(Name = "Bar")]
    Another
}
```

With this view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectStatus)
```

Locally it displays `Foo` as expected.

However when I publish it displays: `First`.

I cannot figure out why.

### Update

If I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code) approach it works both locally and when published. But I'm not looking for a workaround. So I'd still like to know what's causing this odd issue.

Comment: How are you publishing? Have you definitely replaced all the old DLLs with the new ones?

Comment: I publish using Web Deploy and the publish profile is set to delete everything on the host before uploading

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24406117/4270650)?

Comment: Nifty solution. But I'm not looking for a workaround. I'd like to know why it doesn't work as expected. Is it a known bug? Is something missing on the server?

Comment: This is nit-picky, but what happens if you use the `[DisplayName]` attribute instead?

Comment: I'll give that a try. But the deploy process is a bit troublesome so it'll take a few days :(