# How to get enum's Display name from integer

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, enums

I have been trying to get the value inside of `[Display(Name = '')]` to display with an integer input. I've tried what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730907/how-find-the-enum-name-for-corresponding-value-and-use-it-in-displayfor) post said to do but I'm getting errors - I think it's because I'm in .Net Core not Framework. Here is the code trying to display the display name:

```cs
@Enum.GetName(typeof(StateEnum), Timelineinfo.State) //Timelineinfo.State is an int
```

The enum (truncated because it's too long):

```cs
 public enum StateEnum
        {
            Alabama, Alaska, [Display(Name = "American Samoa")] AmericanSamoa, Arizona,
            Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware, 
            [Display(Name = "District of Columbia")] DistrictofColumbia, //continues onwards...
       }
```

Comment: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2487/c---how-to-display-friendly-names-for-enumerations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995593/how-to-display-the-name-of-enum-display-attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225729/enum-value-from-display-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enum value from display name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225729/enum-value-from-display-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string GetEnumDisplayName<T>(T value) where T : Enum
{
    var fieldName = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value);
    var displayAttr = typeof(T)
        .GetField(fieldName)
        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
    return displayAttr?.Name ?? fieldName;
}
```

Then invoke it like:

```
var displayName = GetEnumDisplayName(StateEnum.AmericanSamoa);
```

**EDIT** If `Timelineinfo.State` is an integer, you can use invoke:

```
var displayName = GetEnumDisplayName((StateEnum)Timelineinfo.State);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would work except I wouldn't be able to just say "AmericanSamoa" for example. The thing that goes after StateEnum would change depending on what page I am on. However, I can get what goes there by doing ```@Enum.GetName(typeof(StateEnum), Timelineinfo.State)``` Is there someway I can do something like: ```GetEnumDisplayName(StateEnum.Enum.GetName(typeof(StateEnum), Timelineinfo.State)```?

Comment: @Bubinga is `Timelineinfo.State` an `StateEnum` value? If so, then you can call `GetEnumDisplayName(Timelineinfo.State)`

Comment: @Bubinga I've edited my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Sorry, Timelineinfo.State is an int.

Comment: @Bubinga check the edit. `GetEnumDisplayName((StateEnum)Timelineinfo.State)`

Comment: lol, I put in your edited code wrong. It works, thanks! :D